# Como puedo cambiar el estado de dos checkbox

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox

Estoy queriendo poner dos opciones con checkbox en react native y no logro hacer que cambien de estado, al darle click no pasa nada no se si la palabra reservada onClick esta mal, ya que en algunos tutoriales que vi me dicen poner onPress, les paso el código para que vean como tengo.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, CardItem, Content, Form, ListItem, Button, Text, Body } from 'native-base';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';

class ope extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            one: false,
            two: false
        };
    }

    onePressed = (event) => {
        this.setState({ one: true, two: false });
    }

    twoPressed = (event) => {
        this.setState({ one: true, two: false });
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Form>
                        <ListItem>
                            <CheckBox
                                checked={this.state.one}
                                onClick={this.onePressed.bind(this)}

                            />
                            <Body>
                                <Text>Organizacion/Empresa</Text>
                            </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <CheckBox
                                checked={this.state.two}
                                onClick={this.twoPressed.bind(this)}

                            />
                            <Body>
                                <Text>Persona Fisica</Text>
                            </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                        <CardItem footer bordered style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Button primary onPress={() => navigation.push('organizacion')}>
                                <Text> Siguiente </Text>
                            </Button>
                        </CardItem>
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default ope
```

Lo único que quiero es que se pueda clickear sobre el, y poner y quitar el check nada mas. Les agradecería cualquier ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En react-native la función onClick no esta, tendrías que usar el onPress() de lugar de onClick

```
<Button
  onPress={() => {
    alert('You tapped the button!');
  }}
  title="Press Me"
/>
```

## https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches